# WebView not recognizing any mouse events. Trying to get the side back/forward buttons to register

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, webview

Im working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, C#, WPF

My webview doesnt pick up ANY mouse events.

I need to enable to side buttons on the mouse to trigger going back and forward. I have the code for going back/forward just need to pick up the side mouse clicks.

```
void MainPage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
        {
            Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
            if (pt.Properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
            {
                MainPage.Current.WebRightClicked = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

The web.RightClicked is just a test to see if I can even get to it. I really want to pick up the two side buttons on the mouse where someones thumb goes. To enable going back and forth between history. Almost all major Web Browsers have this feature.

Comment: please post your code if you would like others to help

Comment: It's a very large app with a bunch of classes, and I don't have much code to post except 

MainPage.PointerPressed += MainPage_PointerPressed;

I have that for webView, webOverlay, webContainer. this.PointerPressed.. every pointerPressed event you can think of and just nothing gets fired.

All of them and just nothing gets picked up if my mouse if over my webView when i click.